# How to edit standalone.xml file dynamically in keycloak

Tags: java, dockerfile, keycloak

I am trying to edit the standalone.xml through docker and trying to add but the keycloak is taking its `standalone.xml` . But I am able to see the changes inside the standalone.xml file. I need to add this line in standalone.xml file

```
 <provider>module:org.keycloak.examples.event-sysout</provider>
```

Also tried hot deployement but then can't fetch third party libraries code

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, it seems in a docker container by default standalone-ha.xml is used. You can find this in /opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh.
Second, I think after changing configuration file you'll have to restart keycloak server (container).

Not sure what do you mean by "dynamically". But it will be easier to modify the file locally and build a custom docker image. Dockerfile may look like:

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:6.0.1
ADD <path on your system>/standalone-ha.xml /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

Comment: I have done with that , but the problem I am facing is that keycloak is taking it's standalone.xml from it's memory when it gets started . It is not taking the updated standalone.xml . Next I can see the changes of standalone.xml in the docker container .

Comment: Just to double-check - did you try to change `standalone-ha.xml` instead of `standalone.xml`?

Answer (score 5):

You can not replace or overwrite standalone-ha.xml/standalone.xml without jboss-cli on docker image. Only need to create a sh file and put inside startup-script folder. During initializing it will start and configure your file.

keycloak-cli

```
embed-server --server-config=standalone-ha.xml --std-out=echo 
batch

/subsystem=keycloak-server:list-add(name=providers, value=module:org.keycloak.examples.event-sysout)

run-batch 
stop-embedded-server
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM jboss/keycloak:latest

COPY keycloak.cli /opt/jboss/startup-scripts/keycloak.cli
```

Answer (score 4):

Might be a little late . but I found out you can edit on the dockerfile.

```
FROM quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:11.0.0

RUN sed -i -E "s/(<staticMaxAge>)2592000(<\/staticMaxAge>)/\1\-1\2/" /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -E "s/(<cacheThemes>)true(<\/cacheThemes>)/\1false\2/" /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
RUN sed -i -E "s/(<cacheTemplates>)true(<\/cacheTemplates>)/\1false\2/" /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml

RUN sed -i -E "s/(<staticMaxAge>)2592000(<\/staticMaxAge>)/\1\-1\2/" /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
RUN sed -i -E "s/(<cacheThemes>)true(<\/cacheThemes>)/\1false\2/" /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
RUN sed -i -E "s/(<cacheTemplates>)true(<\/cacheTemplates>)/\1false\2/" /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/configuration/standalone-ha.xml
```

ref : https://github.com/anthonny/kit-keycloak-theme/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: But as @Yuriy P noted, standalone-ha.xml and not standalone.xml

Answer (score -2):

You should go to that running docker container and change in there. 
The best is, use docker manager like Kitematic https://kitematic.com/

Select running keycloak container, click EXEC icon, cd  keycloak/standalone/configuration, vi standalone.xml, :wq to exit, restart docker image through Kitematic, should work

Comment: the question is, after you did that magic and restarted your docker, does your file was changed to whatever you wanted?

Comment: another thing I was doing, download keycloak zip, and run server yourself: "sh keycloak-6.0.1/bin/standalone.sh --server-config=standalone.xml"    with modified xml

Comment: Yes the file had changed but keycloak was not able to fetch new edited xml file even after restart of container

Comment: I downvoted this answer, since it is not a good idea to edit files inside a docker container. If the container gets recreated all changes are gone. This is usually not wanted.

Comment: Whatever makes you happy @Arigion :)