# Enable X509 Certificate User Authentication In Keycloak With Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, x509

I'm fairly new to kubernetes, so forgive me for my ignorance on this topic.

I am trying to set up x509 authentication in keycloak. This [guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_x509) indicates that I need to edit a standalone.xml file and add my configurations there.

I'm not too sure how to edit this file on launch of the instance and copy my Java Key Store into the container image.

Comment: Apparently, it is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474253/how-to-edit-standalone-xml-file-dynamically-in-keycloak

Comment: This looks like it may work. I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replica of [How to edit standalone.xml file dynamically in keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474253/how-to-edit-standalone-xml-file-dynamically-in-keycloak)

You're going to need to dynamically create a keycloak image, then use that image for your configs.